What's up with the [cipher]?
We have the tag cipher having 103 questions.
When should this tag be used, if ever? Isn't having encryption enough?

maybe: cipher is about actual ciphers and their design (AES and stuff) and encryption is meant broader and rather targets using cipher for encryption and the question has some question f.ex. about the modes or other higher-level stuff.

The synonym was approved, so I've marked this as [tag:status-completed].

I don't really see a valid use for it.
If you want to talk about encryption in general, well, use encryption.  If you want to talk about specific kinds of ciphers, use block-cipher, stream-cipher or classical-cipher (and/or one of the more specific tags we have for subsets of those).  I don't see much of a gap between those.
IMO, cipher should be made a synonym for encryption.  In fact, I just proposed that tag synonym.  Go vote for it.
